# Images align with each other in table headers

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/110/)**. How can I make the images in `th` align with each other? Some titles below the images appear to be too long and pushing the images up a bit. I have tried removing `padding: 20px;` and given it a fixed height but failed. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<table id="comparetable" class="blueshine">
<tr>
<td class="blank"></td>
<th><img class="thumbnail" src="image.jpg"><p>jhjhjhik iukiuk iukiu</th>                                       
<th><img class="thumbnail" src="image.jpg"><p>jhjhjhik</th>
<th><img class="thumbnail" src="image.jpg"><p>jhj isdoi idi93</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="rowTitle">Price</td>                                                                                   <td>$4.5</td>
<td>$1.5</td>
<td>$3.5</td>                           
<td>$1.5</td>
</tr>
.....
</table>
```

CSS

```
/* START COMPARISON TABLE STYLES */
#comparetable {width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; text-align: center; margin: 4em 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
#comparetable tr {background: transparent!important;}
#comparetable td,
#comparetable th {padding: 20px; text-align: center;}
#comparetable td.rowTitle {text-align: left;}
.blank {background: none!important; border: none!important;}
.blueshine th {background-color: #b8cee2; font-size: 22px; color: #0c3053; text-align: center; font-weight: 600; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #e0ecf7; border: 1px solid #9fb6c8; }    color: #222;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.thumbnail {width:80px;height:60px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

`th { vertical-align:top }`

Should do the trick: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/111/)

Answer (score 1):

best it's to add a second row of `th`: in first one you put images (with css rule `vertical-align: top`) and in second one you'll put titles with same css rule.

This would be best solution when you have images with different heights and/or titles with differents heights.

More. if you have no images, titles will stay at same line.